# Workaround in JMeter for Autorization Bearer from Microsoft login (for single page application with specific organizational service accounts)

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jmeter, authorization, single-page-application

Single page application with specific organizational service accounts uses microsoft authorization (2.0).
To pretend in JMeter as user working with this application, it is enough to have Bearer access_token and then pass this Bearer in header of JMeter script requests.
I can manually login with user credentials in browser, get Bearer and set up it as variable in JMeter in API requests headers and successfully continue to work with application functionality.

Also I can login in WebDriverSampler (and I suppose, can emulate with WebDriverSampler another user's actions with application like in "browser").

What is the simplest and shortest way, having all above, to get Bearer somehow for API calls in a script without time-consuming or programming-oriented complex solutions? Is it possible somehow to use WebDriverSampler requests for parsing Bearer?

On this stage, the goal is to collect (and generate) Bearers, which have long time of life, with intention to use this set of Bearers for multi-session JMeter "users" later. (Because users amount is under cost constrtaints with users service accounts, i.e. I have 1 provided user only).

Will be very appreciated for grace tips and advices with such kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to use i.e. [BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) for capturing the traffic between the browser orchestrated by the WebDriver Sampler and the backend, this way you will be able to extract [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header value and i.e. store it into a CSV file for later re-use.

In general it should also be possible to replicate the browser's authentication flow with JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers as browsers don't do any magic, they just send [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and display the responses so [well-behaved JMeter test should generate the same network footprint as the real browser does](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)